# Cypress - can I suppress printing of my typed text with cy.type(text)?

Tags: cypress

Testing with Cypress, when I run .type(text) the text entered appears on the output. In the case of usernames & passwords this is not desirable. Is there any way I can suppress this? Example:

```
cy.get("[type='password']")                 
        .click()                                    
        .type(pw)                                   
        .should('have.value', pw)
```

Comment: I assume you are typing in the password so you can log into to some system and you are saying the output has the password displayed in all its glory and you don't want that. Does it do that if you remove the .should()? If you are just trying to log in you don't need to assert that the password is in the text box, you only care about that you logged in? Correct?

Comment: I tried and it did not supress my output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help you, but you could try this:

```
cy.get("[type='password']").then(($input)=>{
            $input.val('YOUR PASSWORD');
        })
```

I did this and did not see the password in my Cypress GUI.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments) you should be able to suppress this by setting the `log` option to `false`. If omitted it defaults to `true`.

IE,

```
cy.type('example', { log: false })
```

Comment: I would say, the ideal way of using as per document, suggested by James McMahon `cy.get('input[name="pwd"]').type('somepassword', { log: false })`